# Getting ERR_TIMED_OUT un Chromium when trying to run a pagekite daphne server on Linux

Tags: networking, network-programming, daphne, pagekite

I want to run a Python backend for a website with pagekite and daphne.
I use the following commands:

```
daphne -b 0.0.0.0 -p 8000 main:app
```

And:

```
python3 pagekite.py 0.0.0.0:8000 https://something.pagekite.me
```

Or:

```
python3 pagekite.py 8000 https://something.pagekite.me
```

This is pagekite:

```
>>> Hello! This is pagekite.py v1.5.2.201011.                   [CTRL+C = Stop]
    Built-in HTTPD is on localhost:35831, secret=CCV0mPEbKJ+ZGhi_7SQT+MYr      
    Connecting to front-end relay 139.162.152.224:443 ...                      
     - Relay supports 10 protocols on 19 public ports.                         
     - Raw TCP/IP (HTTP proxied) kites are available.                          
     - To enable more logging, add option: --logfile=/path/to/logfile          
    Abuse/DDOS protection: Relaying traffic for up to 5 clients per 10800s.    
    Quota: You have 20 days, 5.0 tunnels left.                                 
~<> Flying localhost:8000 as https://something.pagekite.me/                       
    93.153.49.187 < https://something.pagekite.me:443 (localhost:8000)            
 << pagekite.py [flying]   Kites are flying and all is well.
```

In both cases (I tried both commands) I get a time out.I tested in Chromium and Firefox on Linux Mint 20.2. The internet clearly works, because I can google no problem and also type this. Thanks for your help!